# Что делает данный скрипт bash

Tags: ubuntu, bash

не совсем могу понять что делает команда `var='ls-la'`
Как я понимаю скрипт создаёт пустой файл выводит его содержимое, а после копирует его в две других глобальных переменных. Или я не прав?

```
#!/bin/bash
#!bin/sh
    var='ls-la'
    touch $1
    echo $var > $1
    cp $3 $2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Кажется этот скрипт - жертва редактора, который не придаёт значения знакам препинания.

```
#!/bin/bash
#!bin/sh

# первая строка выше - shebang.
# Выбирает интерпретатор для кода в этом файле (Unix only)
# вторая строка - испорченный бывший shebang. Ничего не значит.

# полагаю, редактор поменял кавычки и подредактировал пробелы
# получилось присвоение странной строки,
# а должно быть выполнение осмысленной команды
# было var='ls-la'
var=`ls -la`

# создаёт пустой файл с именем первого аргумента,
# если файл уже существует, обновляет его дату
# (следующая команда делает эту бесполезной)
touch $1

# записываем текст из переменной var в файл с именем из первого аргумента
# переменная var теперь содержит многострочный текст,
# заключим её в двойные кавычки, чтобы сохранить форматирование
# было echo $var > $1
echo "$var" > $1

# копируем файл с именем в третьем аргументе
# в файл с именем во втором аргументе
cp $3 $2
```

Comment: а что, вторая строка `#!bin/sh` несет какой-то сакральный смысл ?)

Comment: `# копируем файл с именем в третьем аргументе
# в файл с именем во втором аргументе` 
- хм, а если во втором аргументе не файл ? да и как-то глупо копировать файл в файл, так как мы по сути тупо перезаписываем один файл вторым;
 да и в кавычки тоже не помешает, на всякий случай, взять, а то вдруг имя попадётся с пробелом.

Comment: @Zt. , Команда `cp` принимает два (или больше) аргумента. Все - имена файлов (иногда каталогов). Ничего с этим не поделаешь. И да, она просто создаёт копию файла, ни больше, ни меньше.

Comment: @Zt., вторая строка - ничего не значащий комментарий. Первая кое-что значит в Linux - помогает выбрать правильный интерпретатор для кода в файле.

Comment: `Ничего с этим не поделаешь.` - причем тут это ? я говорю о не совсем корректном пояснении в вашем ответе и про то что о файле/каталоге лучше упомянуть в самом ответе во избежание неправильного понимания. `вторая строка - ничего не значащий комментарий...` и это тоже лучше добавить в ответе раз уж вы взялись за причесывание кода автора вопроса.

Answer (score 2):

скрипт принимает 3 параметра - имена файлов. вначале создает файл с именем первого параметра и записывает туда текст 'ls-la' (странный текст, но думаю, там опечатка). А потом копирует файл, имя которого в третьем параметре в файл, имя которого - второй параметр. И все.